# create application WebRTC

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

how create a WebRTC (video, audio & message) chat via socket.io
on this application you can:

1. talked to specify user.
2. talked with several users at the same time (notion of room).
3. the user can accept or reject the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [WebRTC in the real world](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) and to [Building a webRTC Video Chat Service On Nodejs and Krakenjs](http://webdevinthecloud.com/2013/12/20/building-a-webrtc-video-chat-service-on-nodejs-and-krakenjs/). Also, you can see [Advanced chat using node.js and socket.io – Episode 2](http://www.tamas.io/advanced-chat-using-node-js-and-socket-io-episode-2/).

Answer (score 2):

There are many frameworks geared towards that specifically. Check out https://simplewebrtc.com/ and http://easyrtc.com/ as solid alternatives.

Note that for multiparty calls you may need to add a server component to handle the media itself.

Comment: thanks for this answer but I dont hope use this frameworks because i will do how create own framework and i will run this app in the local network.

Comment: @ХалидХан SimpleWebRTC is run entirely on your own servers. The server side component can be any node.js application (example is called Signalmaster), and the front end is not a framework, it's a library for managing multiple sessions and normalizing cross-browser behavior. It can be used within any existing framework, because it's just a drop-in library.